# How to list data return fromJson in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

**My API call:**

```dart
Future<List<SongData>> _getMetadata() async {
    Uri url = Uri.parse('https://radioactivefm.gr/live/api/getCoverJson.php');

    final response = await http.get(url);

    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    print('data: $data');
    return SongData.fromJson(data);
  }
```

I can't declare this way, showing A value of type 'SongData' can't be returned from the method '_getMetadata' because it has a return type of 'Future<List>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<List<SongData>> _getMetadata () async {

Uri url = Uri.parse('https://radioactivefm.gr/live/api/getCoverJson.php');

final response = await http.get(url);

var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

print('data: $data');
return data.map((e) => SongData.fromJson(e)).toList();
}
```

Try this and please share the shape of the received data.

Comment: Solved! 
List<SongData> songs = data.map((e) => SongData.fromJson(e)).toList();
    print('data: $data');
    return songs;

add this

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line under

```
List<SongData> songs = data.map((e) =>SongData.fromJson(e)).toList();
print('data: $data');
return songs;
```